# Scala type inference of implicitly resolved anonymous functions

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion

While trying to grasp Scala implicits, I ran into this type inference problem:

```
object Demo extends App {

  def demo(f: (Int, Int) => Int) = ???

  demo((a: Int) => 42)
  demo((a) => 42) // <-- any tricks to make this compile?

  implicit def f1Tof2(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int =
    (a: Int, b: Int) => f.apply(a)

}
```

What's the reason behind the compiler's inability to infer the type correctly? Any tricks to make it work?

Comment: Make sure to also include relevant messages.

Comment: Good point! The compile error is "missing parameter type".

Comment: In my case compiler says: `wrong number of parameters: expected 2`.Compiler does not know that type of `(a)` is `Int` (because it is not specified), so it cannot apply implicit.

Comment: if a is generic type then you need to make a generic f1Tof12 method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. When you call `demo((a, b) => a + b)` (for example), the compiler is already expecting an `(Int, Int) => Int`, so it will infer `(a, b) => a + b` as `(Int, Int) => Int`, since it has the correct shape.

However, when you call `demo(a => 42)`, the compiler sees a `Function1[?, Int]` as the argument, with no indication as to what the parameter type is. Since `demo` expects a `Function2`, the only way this can compile is if the compiler can find an implicit conversion from the passed argument type to `(Int, Int) => Int`. But it can't, because it doesn't know the type it's converting *from*. It cannot just assume it will a `Int => Int`.

There are only two ways to make this work.

1.)  Explicitly declare the parameter type of the anonymous function, like you have done already. This is the only way the implicit conversion can be applied.

```
demo((a: Int) => 42)
```

2.) Provide an overload for `demo` that accepts a `Int => Int`.

```
def demo(f: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = f(1, 2)
def demo(f: Int => Int): Int = demo((a, b) => f(a))

scala> demo(a => 42)
res3: Int = 42
```